# mount -t cifs results in 'cannot mount readonly' error

Tags: mount, samba

I am trying to mount directory located on local network.
I am using :

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user //192.168.0.106/shared /home/user/point
```

And I get following error :

```
mount: /home/user/point: cannot mount //192.168.0.106/shared read-only.
```

It is shared via Samba.
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, use as `mount -t cifs -o vers=3.0,domain=WORKGROUP,username=user //192.168.0.106/shared /home/user/point`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Solved. I just had to install **cifs-utils** package.

Comment: This must be the most confusing error ever.

Comment: This is also the correct solution for debian linux.

Comment: Same worked for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS